# Por quê não criar uma distribuição Ruby on Rails que funcione bem no Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

Tá legal, sendo direto, como ter um ambiente de desenvolvimento Ruby On Rails que funcione bem no SO Windows? Já tentei instalar a versão mais nova Rails 5 pela prompt, mas sempre que vou criar uma aplicação dá erro, também já tentei o RailsInstaller e não funcionou, tentei configurar o Sqlite mas também não funcionou, segui tutorial e tudo. Se não existe uma coisa como uma distribuição RoR para Windows que seja atualizada, rápida e que funcione tão bem quanto no Mac ou distribuições Linux, por quê a comunidade que já está bastante envolvida e experiente com o framework, não criam uma que realmente seja?

Comment: Está tentando criar com qual versão? Usando `Windows 10` eu consegui criar uma aplicação com o `rails 4` com o `ruby 2.1`. A versão mais atual do `ruby` que fazia o meu `rails` falhar, quando tentei criar uma aplicação com `ruby 2.3` estava dando problema nas `gems`. Veja se a combinação: `rails 4 + ruby 2.1 (ou 2.0)` serve para você.

Comment: Você também tem a opção de usar o novo recurso do  `bash on ubuntu` do `Windows`: https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10

Comment: Estou utilizando Windows 7. Obrigado @GabrielKatakura pela sua ajuda, vou tentar fazer o que você disse, embora ache que isso não resolve o real problema exposto pela questão. Pois quero que o Rails funcione tão bem no Windows quanto em Mac e distribuições Linux. Versões novas sem compatibilidade e sem mencionar que Rails super lento no Windows.

Comment: @GabrielKatakura Infelizmente o que você disse não resolveu, e agora nem mais a aplicação quer criar.

Comment: Sinceramente, eu não sei como solucionar o caso com `Windows 7`, como eu havia dito, o meu funcionou com `Windows 10`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Resumindo, referente a pergunta descrita no título**

> Por quê não criar uma distribuição Ruby on Rails que funcione bem no
>   Windows?

É equivocado dizer isso, pois O RoR funciona muito bem em ambiente Windows. O que afeta o funcionamento são as dependências terceiras que o app utiliza. Normalmente gems e plugins mal escritos ou sem suporte adequado.

Não pode misturar as coisas. O framework RoR é uma coisa e o projeto RoR com Gems específicas é outra. Importante também não confundir a linguagem em si, o Ruby é independente do RoR, O RoR é um framework escrito em Ruby. Comparativamente, é a diferença entre PHP e ZendFramework, Laravel, CakePHP. O PHP é uma linguagem e os demais citados são frameworks.

O problema que você tem pode ser devido a gems que não proveem suporte adequado para o seu ambiente (Windows). Não está claro sobre qual gem ou plugin está tendo dificuldade por isso não dá para chegar a uma resposta clara de como resolver. Como resultado, o que você tem é tentar compilar essas dependências com diversas gambiarras, devido a falta de suporte, e isso resulta num mal funcionamento do seu app, normalmente roda muito mais lento do que em outras plataformas. Pelo que entendi é isso que você fez.
Mas não pode culpar o Ruby e nem mesmo o RoR.

Basicamente, as suas opções:

1. Mudar para ambiente Linux só por causa de uma gem ou um plugin.. rsrs
2. Procurar uma dependência (gem, plugin) alternativa que proveja suporte adequado e garantido.
3. Você mesmo escrever a sua própria gem/plugin.

**Dando continuidade a esse trecho:**

> Se não existe uma coisa como uma distribuição RoR para Windows que
>   seja atualizada, rápida e que funcione tão bem quanto no Mac ou
>   distribuições Linux, por quê a comunidade que já está bastante
>   envolvida e experiente com o framework, não criam uma que realmente
>   seja?

Essa parte da resposta ficou um pouco estensa e pode ser removida se alguém interpretar como fora de escopo, mas resolvi publicar assim mesmo. Todavia,  como está indagando isso na pegunta, revolvi deixar claro o que acontece. 
Saliento que é opinião pessoal de alguém que trabalha com vários ambientes. Eu trabalho com linux, windows, mac. Com linguagens diversas também, incluindo Ruby, e minha principal é PHP. Segue leitura abaixo:

Não tenho a pretensão em fazê-lo desistir do RoR, mas sim conscientizar sobre a realidade. Esteja ciente sobre a diferença.

Entendo a frustração pois lido com RoR desde 2011 e sempre foi uma via crucis compilar projetos com gems e plugins que não proveem suporte adequado a Windows e em muitos casos não proveem suporte nenhum. É comum vermos gems abandonadas há mais de 6 anos. Em 2011 pequei um projeto onde uma gem estava abandonada há 4 anos e continua abandonada hoje. Mas o projeto depende dessa gem e usa até hoje. rsrs. Ou seja, 9 anos dependendo de algo abandonado. Nesse projeto específico o cliente não queria linux de jeito nenhum.
Para fazer funcionar, tive que forçar o uso paralelo de cygwin. Em outras situações tive que usar virtualbox ou vmware. **Simplesmente horrível**.

O RoR ou o ruby em si, não tem nada contra Windows e provê um bom suporte, mas infelizmente os que aderem ao Ruby são normalmente "windows haters" (no sentido pejorativo, pois acho que pessoas assim são infantis e anti-profissionais). Muitas vezes, propositalmente ignoram suporte a Windows.

O Ruby e o framework RoR são de desenvolvimento colaborativo. O que acontece no mundo do ruby é, o ruby é formado por uma comunidade que faz vista grossa ao Windows por pura "birra" e com isso perdem muito ao ignorar um sistema operacional dominante globalmente.
Assim você tem uma comunidade menor e consequentemente menos pessoas dispostas a colaborar e compartilhar experiências e tampouco dispostas a iniciar nesse ambiente pois mesmo os que se aventuram a iniciar se deparam com esses problemas  considerados toscos.

Em comparação, o PHP cresceu por ser flexível para "qualquer" ambiente (ambientes mais populares). Já provia suporte desde o Windows 98 com servidor [PWS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Personal_Web_Server). Nessa época, quem usava Windows e queria entrar no mundo de desenvolvimento web usava o que tinha mais acessível, e era o ASP sob o PWS (no caso do windows98). O PHP percebeu que para engajar os programadores tinha que prover suporte a esse ambiente e assim o fez. 
Em pouco tempo o PHP que era bastante amador e ingênuo, criado no "fundo de um quintal" por um programador amador que não tinha a menor idéia do fenônemo que estava criando, conseguiu desbancar uma ferramenta construída pela [maior corporação do mundo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft).

Algo que também aumentou a aceitação do PHP por usuários Windows é que ainda sob ambiente Linux era muito mais complicado a instalação e configuração. Na verdade era um pesadelo. Mas sob ambiente Windows bastava jogar umas dlls aqui e ali e estava tudo pronto!

E não pense que era o PHP que fornecia essas dlls e os binários para Windows. Tudo sempre foi fornecido por voluntários e é assim até hoje com algumas exceções.

Quem é mais antigo sabe como era sofrido compilar o php-gd e outras libraries essenciais. No Windows, bastava descomentar uma linha e já estava pronto. Sem firula, sem mimimi. Então o progamador empolgado já ia direto ao que interessa que era programar, seja por diversão ou para trabalho. Como foi tudo fácil, logo o cara se apaixonava e investia tempo na linguagem.

Outro ponto que fez o ASP perder espaco para o PHP é não fornecer compatibilidade para ambiente Linux. De um lado, temos os usuários comuns que usam Windows em sua maioria e de outro lado os servidores web (provedores de hospedagem) que oferecem Linux em sua maioria. Era óbvio que deveria prover suporte para esses dois ambientes. A Microsoft apostou em forçar o uso de servidores Windows mas foi uma aposta "errada" pois nem todos tinham condições de pagar uma hospedagem mais cara para cobrir as licensas de servidores Windows. Além disso havia um marketplace em torno do ASP pois muitos recursos considerados básicos como "upload de arquivo", era preciso comprar um componente a parte. E não imaginaram que o concorrente PHP iria tão longe. No fim, com todas essas combinações o PHP cresceu e praticamente "domina" essa área, independente de existir ferramentas melhores. O que importa é o suporte e a força da comunidade.
Afinal, de que adianta criar algo que você afirma ser melhor se nem ao menos consegue engajar ninguém a usar? Como pode ser melhor se nem ao menos provê o básico que é o suporte e garantia?

O interessante nisso é a Microsoft entendeu a importância do PHP e passou a prover suporte oficial. https://php.iis.net/ e https://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/phponwindows.aspx

Normalmente quando você procura as comunidades de Ruby, se você é usuário Windows, é apedrejado. O primeiro conselho é o mais idiota de todos. "Mude de sistema, use ubuntu, use redhat, use o suse, bla bla bla" Eles começam a brigar entre si mesmos. Simplesmente não querem resolver questões envolvendo ambiente Windows. É ridículo. Acham que fazendo isso vão destruir a Microsoft. Eles se focam mais em te doutrinar a usar o mac ou linux do que com o foco do problema com a linguagem em si, o Ruby.

O sujeito não tem a menor idéia do motivo do usuário estar no Windows. Eu por exemplo, uso softwares de CAD. (solidworks, autocad, etc). Então isso me forçaria a comprar outro PC com linux ou usar o mac (detesto mac mas uso para desenvolver para iOS). É inviável. Ter um segundo PC com linux apenas para rodar um app em RoR por causa de uma gem. Se outras linguagens como phyton e php fazem tudo bonitinho, por que o RoR que se diz melhor não consegue prover algo tão básico?

Se seu tenho uma empresa com 100 funcionários todos sob Windows, então que ótima ideia hein! Vamos jogar no lixo todos esses PCs e comprar 100 Macs. Ou forçar a todos a se adaptarem a qualquer um dessas centenas de distribuições Linux. Afinal, o dinheiro da empresa nasce em árvores. rsrsr

A consequência disso tudo gera um efeito dominó. Há muitas empresas que dependem de sistemas escritos sob o RoR e quando precisam de profissional para dar continuidade (o programador original saiu da empresa), enfrentam uma enorme dificuldade em encontrar um profissional pois são poucos comparando-se com outras ferramentas. Em consequência também o custo é maior, pois o valor é de acordo com a oferta e demanda.

Um sistema que foi criado com uma ferramenta que se vendeu dizendo ser melhor que concorrentes mas no fim das contas se torna mais caro e trabalhoso para prover o mesmo resultado que os concorrentes. Do ponto de vista "business" isso não tem lógica. Não é vantajoso quando se tem um débito ou um lucro menor.

O que falta no Ruby ou no RoR, é os próprios developers e fãs terem uma mentalidade mais madura. Parar com essa criancice que apenas prejudica a eles mesmos. 

Acredito que se não fosse composto por comunidades de haters<sup>(1)</sup>, o RoR já teria desbancado o PHP há muito tempo pois é uma excelente ferramenta e muito produtiva.

<sup>(1)</sup> <sub>Claro que é uma generalização, pois sempre há exceções. Há bons profissionais no mundo RoR que pensam de forma contrária a maioria que está nesse ambiente.</sub>

Comment: Muito obrigado @DanielOmine, você realmente entendeu o que estava perguntando e deu a melhor resposta. A comunidade perde muito com estas atitudes e já fiz esta pergunta desconfiando disso. Você deu uma resposta e tanto. Pois, realmente de que adianta criar algo que muitos afirmam se o melhor se não consegue engajar a grande maioria que utilizam Windows, por uma besteira. Com relação ao início de sua resposta não disse que em si Ruby e RoR são ruins, acredito no poder dessas tecnologias e me engajei a aprender Ruby e me apaixonei, mas quando cheguei no Rails me frustrou bastante.

Comment: Também sei que terei que lidar com diversos SO como desenvolvedor e você já deu exemplos bons do porque. Mas como iniciante e acredito que a maioria também iremos estar utilizando Windows, como também não teram condições de possuir um Mac ou querer utilizar Linux para apenas aprender a uma tecnologia. Não quero sai por aí desenvolvendo projetos, apenas aprender RoR no SO ao qual no momento estou utilizando. Valeu e mais uma vez muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Olá, bom se fossemos expor todos os problemas de criar algo que rodasse bem em todas as plataformas iriamos escrever um belo de um artigo, ao invés disso vamos focar em soluções.

Uma grande dificuldade em usar Windows pra desenvolver são as bibliotecas compiladas, você pode usar `jruby` que tem uma maior resiliência em ambientes Windows.

Mas se você quer realmente ter dificuldade zero e continuar no Windows você pode utilizar o [Cloud9](https://c9.io/) que é um ambiente completo de desenvolvimento nas nuvens.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou ainda se quiser algo local e ter um pouco de trabalho, mesmo assim não sair do Windows pode usar Vagrant. [Esse aqui](https://nandovieira.com.br/usando-o-vagrant-como-ambiente-de-desenvolvimento-no-windows) é um ótimo tutorial para quem quer configurar seu ambiente de desenvolvimento.

Boa sorte.